# Ignoring one of the value when searching the vector of pairs using std::find

Tags: c++

In a given vector of pairs

```
static std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v
```

how can i ignore one of the value when i search the vector using std::find

```
std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), std::make_pair(first int, /*ignored value*/)) - v.begin();
```

Comment: Use `find_if` instead, then you can compare on whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the better algorithm: [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [first](const std::pair<int, int>& elem){
    return elem.first == first;
});
```

Or a different flavor of `find` from [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/):

```
auto it = ranges::find(v,
    first,                      // the value
    &std::pair<int, int>::first // the projection
    );
```